# Populate a linear layout with custom class objects

Tags: java, android, scrollview, android-linearlayout, imagebutton

I'm trying to design a simple app that scrolls horizontally that is populated with image buttons.

I'm able to populate the list but only if I had 6 buttons manually. Isn't there a way I could do this with an array and a loop? Its feels clunky using btn, btn1, btn2 ect.

my linearList is referenced as mLinearList

I haven't set onClickListeners yet.

```
private void fillPaintingGallery() {

        ImageButton btn = new ImageButton(this);
        btn.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.painting1));
        mLinearList.addView(btn);

        ImageButton btn1 = new ImageButton(this);
        btn1.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.painting2));
        btn1.setContentDescription(RenaissanceDatabase.description[1]);
        mLinearList.addView(btn1);

        ImageButton btn2 = new ImageButton(this);
        btn2.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.painting3));
        btn2.setContentDescription(RenaissanceDatabase.description[2]);
        mLinearList.addView(btn2);

        ImageButton btn3 = new ImageButton(this);
        btn3.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.painting4));
        btn3.setContentDescription(RenaissanceDatabase.description[3]);
        mLinearList.addView(btn3);

        ImageButton btn4 = new ImageButton(this);
        btn4.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.painting5));
        btn4.setContentDescription(RenaissanceDatabase.description[4]);
        mLinearList.addView(btn4);

        ImageButton btn5 = new ImageButton(this);
        btn5.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.painting6));
        btn5.setContentDescription(RenaissanceDatabase.description[5]);
        mLinearList.addView(btn5);





    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you use Gridview or Listview for your requirement

```
for (int i = 0; i < RenaissanceDatabase.description[].length; i++) {
        ImageButton btn = new ImageButton(this);
        int id = getResources().getIdentifier("yourpackagename:drawable/painting" + (i+1), null, null);
        btn.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(
                id));
        btn.setContentDescription(RenaissanceDatabase.description[i]);
        mLinearList.addView(btn);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The 'Android' way of doing what you want is with a ListView and an Adapter.  The ListView is the container that holds the list of items.  An adapter controls what is being displayed, and how it's displayed.

Here is a [good example](https://github.com/thecodepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView) of how to populate a list.  You would modify the example so the template view would contain an ImageButton, and the model would have the image uri and the description.